# google maps API highlight areas

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Is there a way to highlight areas with Google Map JS API v3?

I've seen some websites do it

here are some examples:

- http://www.streetadvisor.com/new-allakaket-yukon-koyukuk-alaska
- http://www.homely.com.au/werribee-wyndham-melbourne-greater-victoria
- http://www.realestate.com.au/neighbourhoods/upwey-3158-vic

Answer (score 1):

This is called a polygon.

[See the Google Docs for information.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple)

You can manually set polygon points in JS.